# Node.js app crash after one request sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I send a POST request from front end and I declare my route like below

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

});
```

My app crash and I got `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Here is my full code for route : http://pastebin.com/EnfXu8Vm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve]. The code should be included here on SO. Please [edit] the question and add the code in this post.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send twice the reply to the same request.

So the code here:

```
 if(result){
    res.json({msg:0})
}
res.json({msg:1})
```

You can probably want to do

```
 if (result) {
   res.json({msg:0});
 } else {
   res.json({msg:1});
 }
```

or, to be more similar to your original code (so without `else`):

```
if (result) {
  return res.json({msg:0});
}
res.json({msg:1});
```